# Can I use a return value instead of break?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to use the `return` value in `switch` cases instead of `break`?

```
bool fight(const Fighter& f1, const Fighter& f2)
{
   
    switch (f1.power > f2.power) {
    case 0:
        f1.power > f2.power;
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's legal. But why not just `return f1.power > f2.power;`? No `switch` required.

Comment: Aside: The `f1.power > f2.power;` statement inside the zero case is a no-op.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: What's being changed?

Comment: @FredLarson i tried that but it gives me a different output then i need

Comment: This logic is strange and somewhat misleading, OR you have a bug reversing your result.  You return true if f1.power is _not_ greater than f2.power, by converting a bool to int and returning true when the result is equal to zero (false).  That negation plus unnecessary switch machinery confuses people (possibly even yourself.)  The code is valid according to the rules of C++ but it would not pass my code review.

Comment: If this result is what you actually want, then just do this:  `return f1.power <= f2.power;`

Comment: Actually, the `switch` with `case 0:` reverses the logic. Try `return f1.power < f2.power;`.

Comment: `break;`, `return something;` or the newfangled `[[fallthrough]]` are all good for ending a `case` section.  For older C++ that doesn't have `[[fallthrough]]` a friendly comment `// [[fallthrough]]` tells whoever comes after that it was intentional and not an oversight.